# Find records where lat long values are different for the same base address

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need help writing a query in Oracle SQL Developer which finds where one attribute matches but the corresponding attributes are different. For example, I need to find records where address fields match, but then the latitude and longitude column have different values than the corresponding records.

This is an example of what I am talking about (record #3 is the problem):

```html
ID     Address       latitude   longitude
1     1104 West St     35.3   -90.1
2     1104 West St     35.3   -90.1
3     1104 West St     36.4   -94.2
```

The point of this is to find where lat long values are different for the same base address. The reason multiple records like this exist is because they are different units in the building, thanks in advance.

Comment: What constitutes a `base address` -- the one with the lowest id?

Comment: By base address I just mean address. It is the same value for all records.

Answer (score 1):

Use analytic functions, if you want to see the detailed records.  The idea is to calculate the minimum and maximum latitude and longitude for each address and then compare them:

```
select ID, Address, latitude, longitude
from (select t.*,
             min(latitude) over (partition by address) as minlat,
             max(latitude) over (partition by address) as maxlat,
             min(longitude) over (partition by address) as minlong
             max(longitude) over (partition by address) as maxlong
      from table t
     ) t
where minlat <> maxlat or minlong <> maxlong
order by address, id;
```

If the values are actually stored as floating point numbers, then you might want a little bit of wiggle room:

```
where (maxlat - minlat) > 0.00001 or (maxlong - minlong) > 0.00001
```

(Note:  `abs()` isn't needed because I know which is bigger and which is smaller.)

Comment: Tried this, but I am getting the error telling me the FROM keyword is not found where expected.